# python virtualenv import failures

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

My source tree is as follows. I am using `python3.7`:

```
proj/
  src/
    __init__.py
    module1.py
    module2.py
  venv
  __main__.py
```

`__main__.py` imports `module1`, which imports `module2`. I am running this in a virtual environment. See below:

In `__main__.py`:

```
import src.module1
...
```

In `module1.py`:

```
import module2
...
```

Note that I do have the `__init__.py` file in the `src` directory.

When I run `__main__.py`, I end up getting an import error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module2'`

What I have found is if I run the program outside of the virtual environment, `module1` is able to import `module2`, but in the `venv`, I hit this error. I am stumped as to how to get this work properly as I believe I have done everything correctly here, using absolute imports and an `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Python import's are so sensitive! I broke my entire project the other day...

First:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/proj/
```

Secondly:

```
import src.module2
```

Thirdly:
In main.py if you are calling a single function or variable do

```
from src.module2 import x,y
```

Do this instead of `... import *`

Answer (score 0):

The absolute paths were not used within the `src` modules, so I wasn't actually using absolute paths, which was my problem. In other words, change `module1.py` to be:

```
import src.module2
...
```